# wpf datagrid does not bubble the scrollwheel event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mousewheel, event-bubbling

The scrollwheel does not work on a DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer, although the vertical scrollbar just works fine. I tested with this setup:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Text="Test the Scrollwheel in the Palette" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 1" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 2" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 3" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 4" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 5" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 6" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 7" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 8" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 9" Focusable="True" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 10" Focusable="True" />
        <DataGrid Name="dgProperties" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- Left Column -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" />
                <!-- Right Column -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: screenshot of the data window]

When the Window is resized small enough, a vertical scrollbar appears to scroll through the 10 TextBoxes and the DataGrid with a dozen rows.

When hoovering over the window content, the scrollwheel works great as long as you are over the TextBoxes, but when hovering the DataGrid, the scrollwheel does not cause scrolling.

This makes me think that the ScrollViewer and StackPanel are not the problem. It must be the DataGrid that takes the Scrollwheel event but does not bubble it to the parent ScrollViewer control.

The Focusable attributes I added for a tabbing test, but this seems to make no difference for scrolling.

Is this normal? Do I need more config in the XAML?

Because of other SO posts on similar problems, I added VerticalScrollBarVisibility, but this didn't improve anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you have nested scroll viewers then the inner scroll viewer will take precedence over the parent scroll viewer. This is because you don't want to scroll the outer scroll viewer when scrolling the inner. That's normal behavior of scroll viewers. Otherwise, scrolling the inner scroll viewer would also scroll the outer. Why would you want that? You must move the mouse outside the inner scroll viewer so that the event source changes. Or use the bars to scroll.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the link, the first answer there indeed solved my problem